# Getting a list of qsub jobs that failed

Tags: bash, ubuntu, cluster-computing, qsub

Often I will submit 200 or so jobs to `qsub` at the same time and be overwhelmed with  the `'completed successfully'` message that I miss the few that fail and their associated `'failed'` message

What command do I use to retrieve a list of all failed jobs that have been submitted?

Comment: Which `qsub` are you referring to? Oracle Grid Engine, PBS, other?

Comment: What's query syntax? Could you give us sample of `input` (and  maybe attended `output`)? Dit you already tried anything?

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
while read line; do
    if [ -z "$line" ] ;then
        next
    elif [ -z "${line//*completed successfully*}" ] ;then
        echo The jobs was completed
    elif [ -z "${line//*failed*}" ] ;then
        echo The jobs has failed
    else
        echo Doing something with input: "$line"
    fi
done < <(qsub <query args line>)
```

With this method, you could create variables useables lather in your script:

```
success=()  # Using an array to store even more than one result
while read line; do
    if [ -z "$line" ] ;then
        next
    elif [ -z "${line//*completed successfully*}" ] ;then
        # Assiming result in the form: The job number: #.* completed successfully
        # meaning job number is immediately before the word completed and line
        # space separated:
        jobnr=${line% completed successfully*}
        jobnr=${jobnr##* }
        success+=("$jobnr ok")
    elif [ -z "${line//*failed*}" ] ;then
        jobnr=${line% failed*}
        jobnr=${jobnr##* }
        success+=("$jobnr failed")
    fi
done < <(qsub 20 -cmd -line -args)
printf ": %s\n" "${success[@]}"
```

#### This was tested with:

```
qsub () 
{ 
  for ((i=${1:-10}; i--; 1))
  do
    case $((RANDOM%10)) in 
        1)
            echo The job $i completed successfully.
        ;;
        2)
            echo The job $i failed.
        ;;
        *)
            echo job $i done...
        ;;
    esac;
  done
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If yours qsub jobs are run in parallel with `&`, a good way to wait for jobs and see if some of it ended in failure :

```
nbf=0
jobs -p|while read; do
    wait $REPLY || (( nbf++ ))
done
echo "$nbf jobs ended with failure" >&2
```

You could adapt this example according to your needs (for example change the output of `jobs -p` by a list of specific jobs or print the PIDs in failure or success, ...).

Answer (score -1):

Making some assumptions:

```
qsub ... 2>&1 | grep -vi "completed successfully"
```